# fetch put выдает ошибку

Tags: javascript, fetch

если в методе фетч в боди дать такой объект, то выдает ошибку

TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
--> starting at object with constructor 'HTMLParagraphElement'
|     property '__reactInternalInstance$m7vc8fqqli' -> object with constructor 'FiberNode'
--- property 'stateNode' closes the circle

```
        const updatedContact = {
            id: e.target.id,
            name: nameValue,
            phone: phoneValue,
            email: emailValue 
        }
```

но если вот такой объект, где переменные заменить на строки, ошибки нету

```
        const updatedContact = {
            id: e.target.id,
            name: "dsad",
            phone: "dsds",
            email: "dsdsds" 
        }
```

```
import React from 'react';
import './contact.scss'

export default class Contact extends React.Component{
    _changeContact(e){
        console.log(e.target.id)
        const nameValue = document.getElementById(`${e.target.id}name`)
        const phoneValue = document.getElementById(`${e.target.id}phone`)
        const emailValue = document.getElementById(`${e.target.id}email`)
        const updatedContact = {
            id: e.target.id,
            name: nameValue,
            phone: phoneValue,
            email: emailValue 
        }
        fetch(`http://localhost:3000/contacts/${e.target.id}`, {
            method: "PUT",
            body: JSON.stringify(updatedContact),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => console.log(json))
            
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="contact">

                    <p id={`${this.props.contact.id}name`}>{this.props.contact.name}</p>
                    <p id={`${this.props.contact.id}phone`}>{this.props.contact.phone}</p>
                    <p id={`${this.props.contact.id}email`}>{this.props.contact.email}</p>
                    <button id={this.props.contact.id} onClick={(e)=> this._changeContact(e)}>Изменить</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Очевидно, что у вас `nameValue` и `phoneValue` и `emailValue` - это html элемент, а не значение. И вам не надо в реакте использовать `document.getElementById`

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko спасибо вы правы, как тогда получать данные, если нельзя использовать document.getElementById

Comment: Читать дальше документацию по реакту. Это объясняется обычно почти сразу.

Comment: https://max-frontend.gitbook.io/react-course-ru-v2/ispolzovanie-props Если по простому, в вашем случае можете использовать `this.props.contact.name`

Comment: а в чем смысл брать элементы, у которых статический текст? Если текст статический - ты можешь его сразу и забыть. Если не статический - то у тебя есть события его изменения, на этих событиях меняешь состояние и в итоге у тебя хранятся не элементы а текст